# Confusing Eclipse and Github interactions

Tags: eclipse, git

We are trying to use Eclipse and github on a project, and it is proving to be a real burden because we do not understand how it works. It is difficult to formulate a single question, but let's start with one case:

We have a project in Eclipse that is on github.  Several developers are sharing the archive.  We learn that we want to create a Java EE project rather than a Java project.  We do not want to change the name of the project.  How can this be done?

Further, not knowing this, we tried to change the name from ProjNamet to ProjName2.
When creating a project on git, Eclipse creates it in a local directory:

c:/Users/username/git

In order to push that project out to github, we executed:
git remote add origin github.com/author/projname
git push origin master

As far as we can see, the project appears to be successfully pushed out to github.
In addition to source code, there is:
.project
.gitignore (which just ignores the build directory)
.classpath
.settings

But when I right click on the repository and try to import projects from it to my computer, Eclipse failed

deleting the directory, and clicking on File->import.. and importing from the repository works.
I do not see what the difference is between the one that worked and the one that did not.

Comment: Your question is overly vague, so you'll likely not get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
git remote add origin github.com/author/projname
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back with a more detailed description of an error, if we get one.